# Why my CPU can't handle the 1000 hz rate of my mouse?

Tags: cpu, mouse, lag

Despite using a AMD FX8320 3.5 ghz, each of my mouse movements causes a drop from 60 to 10 fps in 3D applications where the pointer is visible. I suspect that my CPU has something wrong with the 1000 hz of this mouse as I have no problem with my other mouse.

Other information that might help :

- my mouse is a Gigabyte M6900. Specs here http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16826146020
- I can't change its frequency with the official driver
- 15% increase of CPU usage when I move the Gigabyte. 10% with the other mouse (Wacom Intuos 3).
- The issue remains the same whether I connect to 3.0 or 2.0 USB
- Windows 8.1 with all drivers updated
- no malwares have been found by the scans
- My ASRock 970 Extreme3 R2.0 motherboard is unable to transfer massive data in 3.0 USB (transfer rate drops to 0 after few seconds), does this have anything to do with ?

Comment: Do you have all the proper drivers for your motherboard?

Comment: Your problem isn't your CPU.  If mouse movements caused a drop that is a GPU problem.  How did you determine your motherboard is unable to transfer at USB 3.0 speeds?  My CPU release 10 years ago can handle this mouse, so its not a CPU issue, the amount of processing power require for this mouse is non-existant.

Comment: Also, have you updated your graphics driver recently? If the pointer is visible, it means the application hasn't got direct control over the graphics (where it would supposedly render better).

Comment: All my drivers are updated, GPU and motherboard included

Comment: Ramhound : My motherboard is unable to transfer at USB 3.0 as I tried several times : eacht time, the transfer drops to 0 mb/s after few seconds.

Comment: Well then your motherboard is broken. Get a replacement, then we’ll see.

Comment: Ramhound : I suspect the CPU because the mouse frequency is normally handled by the CPU from what I have read.

Comment: The mouse pointer is handled by the graphics sub-system, especially in (DirectX 3D) applications (See [DirectInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee418273(v=vs.85).aspx) for example).

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable all mouse effects (animated cursor, cursor shades and so on). These effects may prevent the graphics subsystem to handel the mouse cursor on itself, causing the main CPU have to draw the cursor on the 3D graphic which causes the performance penalty.